# Missing vertical line in a table, how can I fix it?

Tags: tables

Here is my code:

```
    \begin{table}[!htb]
    \centering % used for centring table
     \begin{tabular}{cccc}
       \toprule
        \textbf{Thickness} & \textbf{Applied Voltage} & \textbf{$n_1$ Initial Trap Density} & \textbf{$K_D$ De-trap Rate Constant} \\ 
       \midrule
   \multirow{3}{*}{\textbf{100$\mu m$}}  &  3kV    &    3.049$\times 10^{-16}$  &    0.0078     \\ \cline{2-4} 
     \multicolumn{1}{l|}{\textbf{}} & 5kV     &  5.4315$\times 10^{-16}$    &    0.0179   \\ \cline{2-4} 
   \multicolumn{1}{l|}{\textbf{}} &  7kV &    6.7786$\times 10^{-16}$       &  0.0324 \\ \hline
  \multirow{3}{*}{\textbf{108$\mu m$}}    &  5KV         &    6.6479$\times 10^{-16}$ &  0.0075      \\ \cline{2-4} 
   \multicolumn{1}{l|}{\textbf{}} &  7kV  &   1.1565$\times 10^{-15}$  &  0.0239 \\ \cline{2-4} 
    \multicolumn{1}{l|}{\textbf{}} &   9kV &  1.4657$\times 10^{-15}$ & 0.0189 \\        \bottomrule
  \end{tabular}
   \caption{aaaaa } % title of Table
   \label{table:parameters}
   \end{table}
```

[image]

Comment: Using vertical rules with `booktabs` is not a good idea.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You might have a look on our [our starter page](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) if you wish to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Gonzalo Medina has already commented, it's generally not a good idea to use vertical bars (or "rules") in a `tabular` environment along with the commands of the `booktabs` package. In fact, some might claim it's *hardly ever* a good idea to use vertical rules in a table, whether or not you use commands such as `\toprule`, `\midrule`, etc. ... In short, do consider getting rid of those vertical rules. Trust me, they won't be missed.

In addition, since you're already using the `booktabs` package, you could also (i) replace the lone `\hline` with a `\midrule` and (ii) lose all those `\cline` instructions.

Separately, you may also want to do something about the vertical alignment of the numerical data points given in columns 3 and 4. Simply centering them is not optimal. One way of getting some good-looking output would be by loading the `siunitx` package and using that package's `S` column type (instead of the standard-LaTeX `c` column type).

With these modifications in place, this is how your table would look like:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs,multirow,bm,siunitx}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry} % choose page parameters to your liking
\begin{document}
\begin{table}
\centering
\begin{tabular}{ccS[table-format=1.4e-2]
                  S[table-format=1.4]}
\toprule
\textbf{Thickness} & 
\textbf{Applied Voltage} & 
{\textbf{$\bm{n}_1$ Initial Trap Density}} & 
{\textbf{$\bm{K}_D$ De-trap Rate Constant}} \\ 
\midrule
\multirow{3}{*}{\textbf{100$\mu m$}}  
   & 3kV &    3.049e-16  &    0.0078 \\ 
   & 5kV &    5.4315e-16 &    0.0179 \\ 
   & 7kV &    6.7786e-16 &    0.0324 \\ 
\midrule
\multirow{3}{*}{\textbf{108$\mu m$}} 
   & 5kV &    6.6479e-16 &    0.0075 \\ 
   & 7kV &    1.1565e-15 &    0.0239 \\ 
   & 9kV &    1.4657e-15 &    0.0189 \\        
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\caption{aaaaa } % title of Table
\label{table:parameters}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Mico, I was about to post the same thing but then you did things like aligning numbers... :D Great!

Comment: @HishamAlghamdi - You're most welcome!

Comment: its not really necessary but doesn't table have the caption above normally?

Comment: @Rico - Whether to place the caption at the top or the bottom seems to be largely a matter of national taste. In some areas it seems to be customary to place all `table` and `figure` captions at the top, and in others the captions are placed below the main part of the float. Leslie Lamport's own style, judging purely by the LaTeX book, seems to be to place table captions at the top and figure captions at the bottom. Clearly, styles and tastes aren't fixed forever, they evolve over time. My recommendation would be to go with whatever convention your organization and culture requires...

Comment: @Mico: wasn't my intention to offend someone, I was just wondering :)

Comment: @Rico - No worries, I wasn't offended. :-)